# How to turn off firstinits for a single entry with biblatex?

Tags: biblatex, bibtex

I have taken the data from the [Steel Statistical Yearbooks](http://www.worldsteel.org/statistics/statistics-archive.html) (from each of them from 1978--2011) and made various plots from it. Naturally I want to cite it. Reading the biblatex documentation, I've chosen the mvreference as the entry type. This is what my `.bib` entry looks like:

```
@mvreference{worldsteel,
    shorthand={WSA78},
    editor={World Steel Association},
    title={Steel Statistical Yearbook},
    year={1978-2011}
}
```

Now, since I also have the `firstinits=true` option set in biblatex, the entry looks like this: [image: Bibliography Entry]

I would perfere it to be spelled out. Additionally, or perhaps this should have been my main question, what should the bibliography entry be for something like this?

Comment: `editor={{Word Steel Association}},`

Comment: @egreg Wow, it doesn't get any simpler than that. Thanks a lot!

Comment: However, the "WSA" is probably the publisher, rather than the editor.

Comment: @egreg The "WSA" could be both. (BTW, the next time a similar question is asked, I'll be sure its a duplicate.)

Comment: I'd still like to know the answer to the general question: "How do I turn off a biblatex option for a specific entry?"

Comment: @Seamus - just use the OPTIONS field in the entry. See Appendix C of the biblatex manual for which options can be set per-entry.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Enclosing an author/editor name into an *additional* set of braces will print it "as is" -- no turning into initials, no changes of the order of firstname/lastname etc. EDIT: Note that this isn't a feature of `biblatex`, but of the `.bib` file format used by BibTeX and Biber.

```
@mvreference{worldsteel,
    shorthand={WSA78},
    editor={{World Steel Association}},
    title={Steel Statistical Yearbook},
    year={1978-2011}
}
```

As for the correct entry type: The standard use case of `@mvreference` is a multi-volume dictionary or encyclopedia, but using this type for a series of Statistical Yearbooks seems acceptable to me. (At least I can't name a better-suited type off the top of my head.)

Comment: Thanks as well! Can someone comment on whether or not this is the proper way to reference something like this?

Comment: @Psirus — Have you tried the "set" entry type? It is essentially a Biber feature, but from what it says in the BibLaTeX documentation (p. 105 s), it very much sounds like what you need. Though, you may need to change your style file for it to work properly, as I don't know if it has been properly implemented yet (I have never used it myself, but I can have a look if you feel like using it).

Comment: @ienissei Thanks, that seems like the correct entry type for this kind of thing, but to be honest I don't really want to make 31 individual entries for this. For now, I'll just leave it at that and come back when my advisor complains (I don't think she will though). I'll use the set entry when the documents I write become important enough to warrant the effort :-)

Comment: @Psirus — As long as you get the desired output, no one should complain about the entry types and fields you use, at least in my opinion :)