# Sorting with biblatex using sortname

Tags: biblatex, sorting

I want to use the `firstinits=true` option of biblatex, and to disable the abbreviations for specific entries, I use `{{authorname}}`, as recommended in a [previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40012/how-to-turn-off-firstinits-for-a-single-entry-with-biblatex). However, biblatex is apparently unable to sort the bibliography in this case. No matter, I thought, I can just provide `sortname` for the few entries where this is necessary. But biblatex seems to ignore this, i.e. Baltasar appears first in my example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[style=alphabetic,firstinits=true]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{references.bib}
    @report{example1,
        author={Buthor, Baltasar},
        title={Baltie's report}
    }

    @report{example2,
        sortname={Author, Archibald},
        title={Archie's report},
        author={{Archibald Author}}
    }
\end{filecontents}
\bibliography{references.bib}

\begin{document}
  \nocite{*}
  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

How do I use the `sortname` field properly?

Edit: I’m using an up-to-date TeXLive 2011, compiling with pdflatex and bibtex. Tried under both XP and Ubuntu.

Comment: I compiled your example, and Archibald appears in the bibliography before Baltasar.

Comment: How do I add a comment to the question? I think my answer would have fit better as a comment. I am new to stack exchange.

Comment: Just use the link "add comment" below the question.

Comment: Use `biber` to get it working. No idea why ...

Comment: user11171, @Thorsten: You need 50rep in order to comment everywhere. Before that you can only add comments to your own questions and their answers. I converted now the post to a comment.

Comment: AFAIK, sorting is done by `bibtex` or by `biber`, not by `biblatex`. But I guess that does not answer your question...

Comment: Sorting will in general work better with Biber. It has a far more complete and sophisticated sorting system, especially for tricky cases.

Comment: If anyone sees the `biblatex` warning about UTF8, suggesting to use `biber`, then use `biber`. This will fix the `sorting` requested by `biblatex`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Adding `sorting=nyt` to the `biblatex` options will fix it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[
    style=alphabetic,
    sorting=nyt,
    firstinits=true
]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{references.bib}
  @report{example1,
    author={{Archibald Author}},
    title={Archies first report}
    }
  @report{example2,
    author={{Archibald Author}},
    sortname={Author, Archibald},
    title={Archies second report}
    } 
  @report{example3,
    author={Archibald Author},
    sortname={Author, Archibald},
    title={Archies third report}
    }
  @report{example4,
    author={Buthor, Baltasar},
    title={Balties report}
    }
  @report{example5,
    author={Cuthor, Charlie},
    title={Charlies report}
    }   
\end{filecontents}
\bibliography{references.bib}

\begin{document}
  % lorem~\cite{example2}
  \nocite{*}
  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

See section 3.3.2 and section 3.1.2.1 of the [biblatex documentation](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex):
`alphabetic`: This style will set the following package options at load time: 
`labelalpha=true`, `sorting=anyt`.

`anyt` will sort by label, then name, then year, then title, which should be ok, as the label is also in alphabetic order, but for some reason (maybe a bug?) it does not work as expected.

Comment: Thanks, that works. In my version of the documentation it says: `The style will set the following package options at load time: autocite=inline, labelalpha=true.`. Anyway, seems a bit counter intuitive.