# When using autocap, how to still get correct alphabetical sorting?

Tags: biblatex, sorting, capitalization

In [How to ensure the first letter of a footnote is always uppercase?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/258212/how-to-ensure-the-first-letter-of-a-footnote-is-always-uppercase) I received an answer as to how proper capitalisation of Arabic surnames beginning with the definite article "al" could be ensured in citations and the bibliographie by using i.e. `\autocap{a}l-Kabīr`. Unfortunately, that approach means that all such names appear under "A" in a bibliography sorted by name (in the case of this example, "K" would be expected).

Is there a way to get both, proper capitalisation and proper sorting?

Comment: This seems to be exactly what `sortname` is for (see p. 27 of the [`biblatex` doc](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf#page=27)). You would probably have `author = {\autocap{a}l-Kabīr}` for right capitalisation and `sortname = {al-Kabīr},` for correct sorting.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, @moewe! I tried to make it work with sortname, adding `labelalpha=true` and changing to `sorting=anyt` as per the discussion in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42382/sorting-with-biblatex-using-sortname. Still doesn't work, though. Could there be a bug in Biblatex (that's what's suggested over at the other question).

Comment: I don't see any reason why you would want to turn on labels via `labelalpha=true` and `sorting=anyt` except of course if you want to use an `alphabetic` style instead of an `authoryear` one.

Comment: BTW: The bug that matth seems to have noted in the post you linked to is not reproducible in my version of `biblatex`, but maybe I'm not getting what he hinted at.

Comment: Now I have done some research myself, I think that `sortname` does not get the same stripping of diacritics and prefix treatment as `author`/`editor` and is read largely as is, so you need to get rid of the `al-` prefix yourself and cannot rely on Biber to do so. `sortname = {Kabīr}` should work.

Comment: Indeed, in the [Biber documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/biblio/biber/documentation/biber.pdf) you can find that fields of `type_name` are "strip[ped of] prefices like 'al-'", in the table on p. 28 you can see that `sortname` is not one of the fields of `type_name` and thus does not get that treatment. (The fields `author` and `editor` do get this treatment, this is why `author = {al-Kabīr}` sorts under "K".)

Comment: @moewe: Sorry for not having commented again earlier - I was so focussed on trying to find a "bug" that I missed the obvious thing, to just remove the article from the `sortname` field. It works just fine now, of course, without `labelalpha=true` and with `sorting=nyt`. Is there any way to get your comment converted to an answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `sortname` field to specify exactly under which name (and where) the entry ought to be sorted (see p. 27 of the [`biblatex` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf#page=27)).

What you have to keep in mind here is that Biber's sorting algorithm does apply the *nosort* options to the `author` and `editor` field and does remove the "al-" there prior to sorting, but does no such thing to the `sortname` field. (Whether or not that is by intention or should be considered a bug is up for discussion. I for one thought this behaviour quite unusual at first [technically Biber does not consider `sortname` to be of `type_name`], but I can definitely see the benefit of not touching the `sortname` field in any way and actually think this is the "correct" behaviour.)
Refer to §3.1.6. *The `nosort` option*, p. 27, of [the Biber documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/biblio/biber/documentation/biber.pdf) for more on the `nosort` option, its default value and what you can do with it.

So in `sortname` you need to give the name as you would like to have it sorted.

```
author = {\autocap{a}z-Zayn, Ahmad}
sortname = {Zayn, Ahmad}
```

or

```
author = {\autocap{a}l-Kabīr}
sortname = {Kabīr}
```